# C9 Error: Spawn disabled for securtity reasons

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide

I am following the steps on http://nodebeginner.org and using C9 as my IDE.  I get this error when I `require` child_process:

**Code:**

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

function start(response) {
  console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");

  exec("ls -lah", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write(stdout);
    response.end();
  });
}

function upload(response) {
  console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello Upload");
  response.end();
}

exports.start = start;
exports.upload = upload;
```

**Error:**

```
Request handler 'start' was called.
child_process.js:243
  var fds = this._internal.spawn(path,

                   ^
Error: Spawn disabled for securtity reasons
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:243:28)
    at child_process.js:31:15
    at child_process.js:77:15
    at child_process.js:38:27
    at Object.start (/mnt/ws/users/mithun-daa/104441/requestHandler.js:6:3)
    at route (/mnt/ws/users/mithun-daa/104441/router.js:4:20)
    at Server.onRequest (/mnt/ws/users/mithun-daa/104441/server.js:9:5)
    at Server.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1134:12)
    at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:108:31)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

C9 prevents you from using child processes for security reasons. You won't be able to use child processes there, try them locally instead.

Comment: is there any other way to do it (Achieve the same as thing the _exec_ is trying to achieve?) I am new to Node & C9.

Comment: @mithun_daa: Not on C9. And if there is one, you're not supposed to use it. Just try it locally.

Comment: what's the point of using c9 if once you write code using a child process you can't use it anymore?